# jQuery storing a reference to $(this)

Tags: jquery

simple question for this code in click function:

```
curSlide = $(this);
alert( curSlide == $(this));
```

how come it traces 'false'?

Answer (score 5):

It's because every time you call `$(...)` jQuery creates a new object.

Hence although the contents of that object might be similar (if not identical), they're *not actually the same object*.

Comment: nice fast respons! thnaks. makes sense.

Comment: ... but how can i test if they are refering to the same - WITHOUT comparing ids of the two elements? e.g. curSlide.attr("id) == $(this).attr("id")

Comment: You need to supply more context about what you're trying to achieve to get a definite answer, ideally in a new question.  For example if it's only one element you _could_ check that `$(a).get(0) === $(b).get(0)`

Comment: I will not supply more context ... cos you have just given me a solution that works :D Thank you very much!

Comment: it may not be the most efficient or concise, though

Answer (score 0):

As @Alnitak says, it's because `$()` makes a new object.  To compare jQuery objects, you can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

```
curSlide = $(this);
alert(curSlide.is(this));
```